# Relation between Range Space and Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a problem in the book Linear Algebra by 'Hoffman Kunze':

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and $T$ a linear operator on $V$. If ${T}^2$ = $0$,
what can you say about the relation of the range of $T$ to the null space of $T$?

I was trying with $R(T^2)\subset R(T)$
and $N(T)\subset N(T^2)$ but couldn't get the answer....

any hint would be appreciated.....

Comment: Your first statement, that $R(T^2)\subset R(T)$  certainly is NOT correct.  Since $T^2= 0$, $R(T^2)$ is all of V!

Comment: Range space of $T^2$ is {0}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, write $T(v)=w,$ then $T(w)=0,$ what does that tell you about $w?$

Hover over the yellow box for the answer.

> Since $T(w)=0,$ then $w\in \mathrm{Null}(T).$ Since $w=T(v),$ and since $T(v)$ was arbitrary, then $\mathrm{Range}(T)\subset \mathrm{Null}(T).$

Comment: I got it...thanxx..